# Generating a binary combination counter in verilog?

Tags: binary, combinations

**Hello everybody**
Can anyone help me to generate a combination counter?
the output that I'm looking for is as follow :
0001
0010
0100
1000
0011
0101
1001
0110
.....
1111

Comment: basically the order is not important. I want to get all the data that have just one in the strings then all the data that have two ones then three ones and so on.

Comment: anyone can help me please? I really appreciate helping me